# How to inject my service class in my controller using guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I want to add DI features to an old codebase that uses simple instanciation of services in the controller layer.

I tried using `@Inject` before my `serviceInterface` field in my controller class. And annotate my ServiceInterface with `@ImplementedBy(ServiceInterfaceImpl)`.

My code looks like below:
Controller class

```
public class MyController {
    @Inject
    ServiceInterface serviceInterface;

    InitContext(..){
        // somecode
        Toto toto = serviceInterface.getToto(); //I get an NPE here
        // other code
    }
}
```

ServiceInterface Code:

```
@ImplementedBy(ServiceInterfaceImpl.class)
public interface ServiceInterface {
     Toto getToto();
}
```

ServiceInterfaceImpl Code:

```
@Singleton
public class ServiceInterfaceImpl implements ConventionServices {
     Toto getToto(){
          //somecode
     }
}
```

I expect that my service will be instanciated, but I get a NPE that indicate that I missed something, I tried adding `@Provides` before my service constructor but nothing changed.

Comment: What's responsible for instantiating your controller class? If you're doing it yourself via a call to `new` then it won't be in a CDI context and none of the dependencies will be injected automatically. I'd guess you're probably not manually instantiating it, but, belt-and-braces...

Comment: How do you construct the Controller? With an Injector like you should or directly by calling the constructor?

Comment: I construct the controller fields using a constructor (InitContext) (If it will help, this is a jsp type off application so basically my controller is linked to a jsp page)

Comment: So you *are* calling `new MyController()` directly in your code somewhere? If so, that's why the dependency is `null`, if you manually construct then you need to manually inject. Otherwise you need to rely on some CDI-aware framework to handle instantiation for you.

Comment: So maybe I was mistaken in choosing Guice as a way to introduce DI to this application. I was thinking that `@Inject` and `@ImplemetedBy` are sufficient to do instanciation of my service object.

Comment: That's not a Guice-specific problem. All CDI frameworks that I know of have that same requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You should inject `ServiceInterface` in your constructor, not as a field injection

Your issue is that you have null values because field injection occurs after constructor injection. So move your injection to the constructor instead of the field injection:

```
public class MyController {
  private final ServiceInterface serviceInterface;
  @Inject MyController(ServiceInterface serviceInterface) {
    this.serviceInterface = serviceInterface;
    Toto toto = serviceInterface.getToto();
  }
  ...
}
```